# static Date from = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()), to = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()) not Working

Tags: java

What is the alternative of getting the

```
static Date from = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()), to = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())
```

since the `Date` is now outdated (and partly deprecated) and it is giving me a `NullPointerException`. I want to get the current system time.

Comment: The `Date` class is not the source of your NullPointerException.

Comment: `new Date()` is just fine. Or `Instant.now()` in Java8. Or what you have (although it's pointless to init the date manually to the current time since that happens by default). `Date` is also not deprecated - there is a nicer more versatile alternative. The only thing deprecated are a few methods / constructors in `Date` that are deprecated since Java 1 or so.

Comment: @zapl That's why this question has now "partly deprecated" ;P.

Comment: It is deprecated when and only when the Javadoc says so. It has some deprecated methods. Not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Calendar`.

```
Date currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
```

In Java 8:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
```